# getting valueState of react-bootstrap-switch

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am using react-bootstrap-switch in react app I am building and am having trouble getting the state of the switch.

This is how I render the switch:

```
<Switch value={'off'} state={this.state.storyStatus} size={'small'} onColor={'danger'} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

I have used this for the change handler:

```
handleChange: function () {
      console.log(this.state);
      //this.setState({storyStatus: !this.state});
  },
```

and this is my initial state method:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        storyStatus: "false"
    };
  },
```

the console.log simply logs the initial state, not the actual state of the switch.

Using the react developer tools I can see the state changing when I operate the switch, but cannot seem to pull value of the switch state.

[image]

Ultimately i would like to change the background colour of an li element based on the state of the switch.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but the console.log still seems to juts pull the initial state, nit the actual state of the button. as its constantly logs false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `handleChange` is defined on the parent component, which renders your `Switch` component. That's why `this.state` refers to the state of this parent component, not the state of your `Switch` component.

In the same way, `getInitialState` defines the initial state of the parent component, where the only thing we define is `storyStatus: "false"`.

To read the value from the `Switch` component, the `onChange` callback gives you access to the component and state ([source](https://github.com/Julusian/react-bootstrap-switch/blob/master/src/coffee/react-bootstrap-switch.coffee#L112)).

So doing

```
handleChange(component, state) {
  console.log(state);
}
```

should do the trick.